# Bootstrap form group

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a bootstrap form input-group like the one illustrated in the image below

[image: bootstrap input group]

What I want to create is a input-group with:

[text field | dropdown | textfield | button | textfield | button]

Any ide's how to do this? I cant get it to work. I get the first textfield and the dropdown in the same group but the rest of the components is placed outside the row / col I have placed my input group in.

Comment: Yes, I can post a jsfiddle when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

;The trick is to set a width on the fields. Did some ugly inline styles, you would have to put that in a style-sheet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount"  style="width:50px">
          <select class="form-control" style="width:90px;-webkit-appearance: none;">
            <option>kg</option>
            <option>gram</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount"  style="width:50px">
          <div class="input-group-addon btn">Flow</div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount"  style="width:50px">
          <div class="input-group-addon btn">Unit</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

See example and result here: http://jsbin.com/poyaqu/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Classes `.input-group-addon` and `.input-group-btn` did the trick. A bit of `border-radius` control with a little jQuery to update the value of dropdown and Bingo! Here is your code:

HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Weight">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          KG
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">KG</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">POUND</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          Flow
        </button>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          Unit / KG
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-default {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.input-group-btn:last-child>.btn {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.btn').html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

And here is a working **[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/e8u7Gl0STF)** for your reference. Cheers!